# Show that if G is a convex polygon in an open hemisphere or in a hyperbolic plane, then

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Gauss-Bonnet Formula for Polygons:

Show that if $G$ is a convex polygon in an open
hemisphere or in a hyperbolic plane, then

$H(G)$ = $2p - \sum a_{i}$ = $\sum b_i - (n - 2)p$ = $ Area(G)\cdot K$,

where $\sum a_{i}$ is the sum of the exterior angles, $\sum b_i$ is the sum of the interior angles, $n$ is the number of sides, and $K$ is the Gaussian curvature.
Also prove this on sphere.

I can divide the convex polygon into triangles and apply

$H(D) = 2p - (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) =  (b_1 + b_2 + b_3) - p$

to triangle and add up the results ($H(G) = 2p - \sum a_i$).

I not sure what to do after, I was wondering if anyone can help me out?

Comment: Is your convex polygon a geodesic polygon?

Comment: I think he implied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geodesic polygon is a polygon whose segments are geodesics. In this case if the geodesic polygon lies in a framed open set of an oriented Riemannian 2-manifold given $b_i$ he interior angle at vertex i, R is the closed region enclosed by the polygon, and K the Gaussian curvature on R,then
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i = (m-2) \pi+\int_D K dS
\end{equation}
As a matter of fact a geodesic polygon has geodesic curvature $k_g=0$, while the exterion angles $a_i$ are related to the interior angles $b_i$ by the relation
\begin{equation}
a_i=\pi-b_i
\end{equation}
Hence, the Gauss–Bonnet formula becomes
\begin{equation}
2 \pi-\sum_{i=1}^{m} (\pi-b_i) = \int_D K dS
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_i = (m-2) \pi+\int_D K dS
\end{equation}
An hyperbolic plane has constant Gaussian curvature −1, while for a sphere $K=\frac{1}{R^2}$